# Update the last element of the array in MongDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

The question might be repeated but didn't find proper answer that handles this condition. The collection is:
**coll1**

```
{
  "temperature_status": "Normal",
  "monthly_record": [
    {
      "date": "2019-02-14",
      "average": "75F",
      "daily_record": [
        {
          "avg": "60F",
          "period": "First Half"
        },
        {
          "avg": "90F",
          "period": "Second Half"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2019-02-15",
      "average": "60",
      "daily_record": [
        {
          "avg": "50F",
          "period": "First Half"
        },
        {
          "avg": "70F",
          "period": "Second Half"
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
  }
```

I want to update ***average*** of ***2019-02-15***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't clearly understand what you try to achieve (update last item of array or update item where date is '2019-02-15').

## If you want to update last item of an array in your documents

Based on your sample (as you used cursor I adapted it to update the whole database, use carefully. If you want to update only 1 document, you should not use `.find({})`

```
const cursor = coll1.find({}).limit(1);

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  const item = cursor.next();
  const update_index = doc['monthly_record'].length - 1;
  coll1.update_one({ _id: item._id },
    { '$set': { `monthly_record.${update_index}.average` :'60F' } }
  )
}
```

## If you want to update an element in an array at a specific index

You said `I want to update average of 2019-02-15`, it means you already know the filter, so you could do it in one query:

```
coll1.update({ 'monthly_record.date': '2019-02-15' },
  { '$set': { 'monthly_record.$.average' :'60F' } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

(Remove `multi: true` if you want to update only first matching document)

Answer (score -1):

Also, to find the first match use [`find_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)